# Error using read.table to import txt into R

Tags: regex, r, import

I was using read.table to import the data in R, the code is like:

```
txt=read.table("C:\\Work\\Network Monitoring\\Text mining syslog\\small set.txt", sep="\t", col.names=c("message", "device"))
```

And in the txt file, each data line is like:

```
%SPANTREE-SP-2-RECV_PVID_ERR: Received BPDU with inconsistent peer vlan id 1 on GigabitEthernet6/21 VLAN49. sn1-65ag-hot-137b
```

Where the first element is a message and the second element is a device, the two elements are separated by a tab.

I got this error message: 
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
line 15 did not have 2 elements

However I was using edit pad pro to check the regex and see the only one tab in line 15 between message element and device element.

Could anyone help with this??

Thank you so much for all the inputs!

So I added fill=TRUE in the read.table command, which is

```
txt=read.table("C:\\Work\\Network Monitoring\\Text mining syslog\\03_28_2MB.txt",sep="\t",fill=TRUE, col.names=c("message","device"))
```

The following data is attached a sample, 40 lines in total. After read.table command, there are three data lines, which are read correctly and those three are line 16, 34, 38 in the following table. (I am sorry the bolding does not work for me in this thread.) So I found all three lines containing label #. I checked the regex, there is no tab around the label #. Do you know how can I avoid this problem?

Really appreciate it!

Sample data:

```
%SPANTREE-SP-2-RECV_PVID_ERR: Received BPDU with inconsistent peer vlan id 1 on GigabitEthernet6/21 VLAN49. sn1-65ag-hot-137b
%USER-3-SYSTEM_MSG: bcm_usd_isr_switch_event_cb:431: slot_num 0, event 2, memory error type 0x1, mem addr 0x1e62, cause bit 0x10020a8  - bcm_usd    dm2-x34x-str-5-10
%USER-3-SYSTEM_MSG: bcm_usd_isr_switch_event_cb:431: slot_num 0, event 2, memory error type 0x1, mem addr 0x580b, cause bit 0x10020a8  - bcm_usd    dm2-x34x-str-5-10
hkb-96cbe-1a /kernel: %KERN-4: tcp_auth_ok: Packet from 207.46.32.161:65261 unexpectedly has MD5 digest hkb-96cbe-1a
hkb-96cbe-1a /kernel: %KERN-4: tcp_auth_ok: Packet from 207.46.32.160:61061 unexpectedly has MD5 digest hkb-96cbe-1a
ash-96cbe-1a fpc5 MIC(5/1) link 2 SFP syslog throttling: %PFE-5: enabling syslogs for receive power alarms and warnings. (0/0) ash-96cbe-1a
%USER-3-SYSTEM_MSG: bcm_usd_isr_switch_event_cb:431: slot_num 0, event 2, memory error type 0x1, mem addr 0x18bae, cause bit 0x10020a8  - bcm_usd   am2-x3sb-xcg-2-1b
/kernel: %KERN-4: tcp_auth_ok: Packet from 207.46.32.161:59634 unexpectedly has MD5 digest  bl2-64c-1a
lon04-96cbe-1a mib2d[1976]: %DAEMON-6-SNMP_TRAP_LINK_UP: ifIndex 678, ifAdminStatus up(1), ifOperStatus up(1), ifName xe-7/2/0  lon04-96cbe-1a
db3-96c-1b snmpd[1640]: %AUTH-5-SNMPD_AUTH_FAILURE: nsa_log_community: unauthorized SNMP community from 10.180.183.76 to 213.199.144.24 (b9hFAPAHa) db3-96c-1b
%USER-3-SYSTEM_MSG: bcm_usd_isr_switch_event_cb:431: slot_num 0, event 2, memory error type 0x1, mem addr 0x1e69e, cause bit 0x10020a8  - bcm_usd   bl2-x3hl-xcg-10-07
db3-96c-1a snmpd[1607]: %AUTH-5-SNMPD_AUTH_FAILURE: nsa_log_community: unauthorized SNMP community from 10.180.183.76 to 213.199.144.23 (b9hFAPAHa) db3-96c-1a
lon04-96cbe-1a mib2d[1976]: %DAEMON-6-SNMP_TRAP_LINK_UP: ifIndex 749, ifAdminStatus up(1), ifOperStatus up(1), ifName xe-7/2/0.0    lon04-96cbe-1a
db3-96c-1a snmpd[1607]: %AUTH-5-SNMPD_AUTH_FAILURE: nsa_log_community: unauthorized SNMP community from 10.180.183.76 to 213.199.144.23 (public)    db3-96c-1a
db3-96c-1b snmpd[1640]: %AUTH-5-SNMPD_AUTH_FAILURE: nsa_log_community: unauthorized SNMP community from 10.180.183.76 to 213.199.144.24 (public)    db3-96c-1b
lon04-96cbe-1a rpd[1946]: %DAEMON-6: EVENT <UpDown> index 263 <Up Broadcast Multicast> address #0 54.e0.32.74.8f.cb lon04-96cbe-1a
co2-96c-1a snmpd[1666]: %AUTH-5-SNMPD_AUTH_FAILURE: nsa_log_community: unauthorized SNMP community from 100.101.103.220 to 207.46.32.88 (public)    co2-96c-1a
lon04-96cbe-1a /kernel: %KERN-4-: port status changed   lon04-96cbe-1a
co2-96c-1a snmpd[1666]: %AUTH-5-SNMPD_AUTH_FAILURE: nsa_log_community: unauthorized SNMP community from 100.101.103.220 to 207.46.32.88 (b9hFAPAHa) co2-96c-1a
HK2-A75BL-SRCH-1 Rib: %BGP-3-NOTIFICATION: received from neighbor 100.96.155.171 (AS 65534) 6/5 (Cease/connection rejected) 0 bytes ???
BLUDCFX01SPINECC01 Rib: %BGP-3-NOTIFICATION: received from neighbor 10.60.132.3 (AS 65247) 2/2 (Open Message Error/bad AS number) 0 bytes bludcfx01spinecc01
was01-96cbe-1b chassisd[1482]: %DAEMON-3: New CRC errors found on xfchip 0 plane 2 subport 16 xfport 4 new_count 1 aggr_count 245862    was01-96cbe-1b
HK2-A75BL-SRCH-1 Rib: %BGP-3-NOTIFICATION: received from neighbor 100.96.155.171 (AS 65534) 6/5 (Cease/connection rejected) 0 bytes ???
fpc2 SYSLOG: %PFE-6: 25 messages lost, message queue overflowed. ams-96gmr-mms-7a
bl2-96c-1b snmpd[1621]: %AUTH-5-SNMPD_AUTH_FAILURE: nsa_log_community: unauthorized SNMP community from 10.55.4.25 to 207.46.32.99 (b9hFAPAHa)  bl2-96c-1b
bl2-96c-1a snmpd[1685]: %AUTH-5-SNMPD_AUTH_FAILURE: nsa_log_community: unauthorized SNMP community from 10.55.68.25 to 207.46.32.98 (public)    bl2-96c-1a
lon04-96cbe-1a /kernel: %KERN-4-: port status changed   lon04-96cbe-1a
bl2-96c-1a snmpd[1685]: %AUTH-5-SNMPD_AUTH_FAILURE: nsa_log_community: unauthorized SNMP community from 10.55.68.25 to 207.46.32.98 (b9hFAPAHa) bl2-96c-1a
bl2-96c-1b snmpd[1621]: %AUTH-5-SNMPD_AUTH_FAILURE: nsa_log_community: unauthorized SNMP community from 10.55.68.25 to 207.46.32.99 (b9hFAPAHa) bl2-96c-1b
%USER-3-SYSTEM_MSG: bcm_usd_isr_switch_event_cb:431: slot_num 0, event 2, memory error type 0x1, mem addr 0xe94, cause bit 0x1002173  - bcm_usd blu-x3hl-xcg-11-12
sin-f6f-edgcom-1a big3d[1956]: 01333001:3: SSLConnect: SSL error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol  sin-f6f-edgcom-1a
bl2-96c-1b snmpd[1621]: %AUTH-5-SNMPD_AUTH_FAILURE: nsa_log_community: unauthorized SNMP community from 10.55.68.25 to 207.46.32.99 (public)    bl2-96c-1b
10.4.143.113-1 SSHD[214436976]: sshd_control.c(274) 54449271 %% exited = 0  db3-lmb-hot-113-01a
lon04-96cbe-1a rpd[1946]: %DAEMON-6: EVENT <UpDown> index 263 <Broadcast Multicast> address #0 54.e0.32.74.8f.cb lon04-96cbe-1a
%USER-3-SYSTEM_MSG: bcm_usd_isr_switch_event_cb:431: slot_num 0, event 2, memory error type 0x1, mem addr 0xe14, cause bit 0x1002173  - bcm_usd blu-x3hl-xcg-11-12
ams-96c-1b snmpd[1616]: %AUTH-5-SNMPD_AUTH_FAILURE: nsa_log_community: unauthorized SNMP community from 10.183.235.204 to 213.199.144.30 (b9hFAPAHa)    ams-96c-1b
lon04-96cbe-1a mib2d[1976]: %DAEMON-4-SNMP_TRAP_LINK_DOWN: ifIndex 678, ifAdminStatus up(1), ifOperStatus down(2), ifName xe-7/2/0  lon04-96cbe-1a
lon04-96cbe-1a rpd[1946]: %DAEMON-6: EVENT <UpDown> xe-7/2/0.0 index 398 <Broadcast Multicast> address #0 54.e0.32.74.8f.cb lon04-96cbe-1a
bl2-96c-1a snmpd[1685]: %AUTH-5-SNMPD_AUTH_FAILURE: nsa_log_community: unauthorized SNMP community from 10.55.4.25 to 207.46.32.98 (public) bl2-96c-1a
bl2-96c-1b snmpd[1621]: %AUTH-5-SNMPD_AUTH_FAILURE: nsa_log_community: unauthorized SNMP community from 10.55.4.25 to 207.46.32.99 (public) bl2-96c-1b
```

Comment: try adding `fill=TRUE` to `read.table` to see what you get (i suspect the data will not be right, but you might be able to see what ended up not working). We'd need to see a portion of the data file to help more.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider filling the missing data (**fill=TRUE**):

```
txt=read.table("C:\\Work\\Network Monitoring\\Text mining syslog\\small set.txt", sep="\t", fill=TRUE, col.names=c("message", "device"))
```

Or using a different delimiter (such as the word **on**):

```
txt=read.table("C:\\Work\\Network Monitoring\\Text mining syslog\\small set.txt", sep="\son\s", col.names=c("message", "device"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `read.delim`, where `sep = "\t"` by default.

```
> txt <- "%SPANTREE-SP-2-RECV_PVID_ERR: Received BPDU with inconsistent peer
          vlan id 1 on GigabitEthernet6/21 VLAN49.  sn1-65ag-hot-137b"
> writeLines(txt, "smallSet.txt")
> read.delim("smallSet.txt", header = FALSE, col.names = c("message", "device"))                                                                                        
                                                                                                     message
1 %SPANTREE-SP-2-RECV_PVID_ERR: Received BPDU with inconsistent peer vlan id 1 on GigabitEthernet6/21 VLAN49
              device
1  sn1-65ag-hot-137b
```